# What is the nature of pragmatism as a claim? Can pragmatism ever be understood as a claim in light of its own conditions?

Tags: truth, meaning, pragmatism

Pragmatism is the suggestion that truth-value and meaning should be talked about in terms of the way we use those terms. All such talk should be hashed out in terms of the *practical bearings* of such words.

What sort of suggestion is this though? Are we to understand the meaning of this suggestion in terms of its practical bearings (as would be consistent with the suggestion of pragmatism)? And if so, do we ever really know what pragmatism is a suggestion of if 'practical bearings' is continually explained by reference to 'practical bearings' (which would seem circular)? Is this conceived as a problem by pragmatists themselves?

Comment: Your first sentence is ambiguous.  Can you clarify what you mean by "those terms"?

Comment: IOW, are you asking about the terms "truth-value" and "meaning" from a pragmatist perspective?  Or about the T-value and/or meaning of *any* term from that perspective?

Comment: Both I suppose. In the question I was admittedly asking about the terms 'truth-value' and 'meaning' specifically (so the last word, 'terms', in the sentence is referring to 't-value' and 'meaning' in the same sentence), but it seems that this objection can very well apply to any term that is predicated over and about in the pragmatist suggestion. That is somewhat the purpose of this question later on when I'm asking how pragmatism can explain the content of its *own* words and standards, such as 'practical bearings' and even the simple seeming phrase 'is useful'.

Comment: Ok then, great question but my answer is too big to type on a mobile phone.  ;)  Will respond later.

Comment: @mobileink Gotcha.

Comment: Pragmatism does not start with meaning and truth, it starts with a community of speakers making assertions that are understood by others to infer other assertions or to call for actions. Social interaction leads to assent or dissent on them, presumably based on practice, these are the 'practical bearings'. Meaning is recovered as inferential role, truth as assertibility "all things considered". The "meaning" of pragmatism itself is to be understood in kind. "Circularity" comes from accepting the regress of explanations in semantic realism, which is its major flaw and which pragmatists reject.

Comment: @Conifold 'Being accepted by the community' is a trait that every statement that carries content could have. It could, and arguably is, the case that the statement 'pragmatism is false' carries use and has 'practical bearings' in the community. The only way pragmatism is interesting is if it offers a standard as to what is meant by 'practical bearings'. This is not begging the question against pragmatism; it is asking why we should think pragmatism is something that is even worth discussing in the first place. Even pragmatists have historically offered explanation of its own standards.

Comment: @Conifold My point is asking how an explanation of these standards is possible granted that a strict form of pragmatism is adhered to, since if every statement is lacking in semantic content outside of its use, then an explanation of the standard of what practical bearings qualify as being preferable seems daunting and subject to the exact same set of problems (Agrippan Trilemma) pragmatism proposes it surpasses.

Comment: The problem is that you are asking for a standard in a realist's sense, some sort of conceptual construct with a truth condition. Pragmatism can recover that for "local" claims and standards within a practice, but asking it about practice as a whole is meaning defective for the same reason as Liar sentences. A global "answer" would be that pragmatism is to be confirmed or infirmed by its overall effect on practice as a whole, including its ever revisable standards, i.e. by its use, and ex post facto, not a priori. This extends hypothetico-deductive attitude to standards to remove circularity.

Comment: @Conifold You might be right. I never stated that I was asking for a realist's standard though, only a sufficient standard. There have been realist solutions offered for the liar paradox, so I'm not quite sure what your reference to the liar paradox is implying.

Comment: "Practical" is not an essence to be grasped, it groups context specific approaches into a family by resemblance, and they are understood by practicing. Pragmatist meaning is linguistic role, Liar sentence that relates only to itself is void of it. Similarly, reasons relate parts of practice to each other, asking of the whole practice for its reason is equally void. But if you ask how pragmatism solves the sceptical trilemma, or why prefer it to realism on semantics, cogent answers can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  The short version of my answer is something like: to me Pragmatism is more like an attitude or orientation than a claim.  If it were a claim along the lines of a definition of truth or reference in terms of practices then it would be circular as you note.  But pragmatists do not (usually) presume to *define* truth and reference (i.e. what they are); rather they tend to explain the way we use those terms, and then (usually) argue that looking for more than that is a waste of time.  At the extreme this means that concepts like truth and reference are vacuous; they are not properties, have no substantial role, and have no explanatory value.  Do a little searching on "deflationary truth" for more on this.

Most (all?) pragmatists are anti-foundationalists, by which I mean they do not offer a "better" foundation (or "claim") than the old ones; rather they reject very idea that we can get at such a foundation.  Not that they disprove it or deny that some such *may* exist.  Maybe a foundation exists, maybe not, but either way arguing about it is a waste of time.

So "how pragmatism can explain the content of its own words and standards"?  By explaining how that content is instituted by and illustrative of our practices, not by appealing to concepts like truth and reference.  The nice thing about this is that is naturalistic, and so compatible with natural science - explaining our practices, which are naturalistic, is something natural science can (in principle) do.

Note that terms like "practical bearings" or even "practices" are not philosophically mysterious, unlike semantic vocabulary like "truth".  The practices of a linguistic community are analogous to the behavior of a population of non-human creatures or of a system of non-living particles: something that can be observed and described scientifically.  So there's no circularity in using such terms to describe how we explain our practices.

BTW, the risk of circularity was/is indeed well known to praggies, and the issues are actually much more complex and subtle than I've indicated.  Plus there is more than one such risk.  For a detailed argument about a possible circularity in the way pragmatists use semantic vocabulary like "true" and "refers" ("semantic" vocab being terms that purport to get their significance from representational relations) see Huw Price's response to Horwich in [Expressivism, Pragmatism and Representationalism](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/philosophy/philosophy-mind-and-language/expressivism-pragmatism-and-representationalism).

Hope that helps.  FWIW the best intro to contemporary pragmatism that I know of is [Pragmatism](http://www.polity.co.uk/book.asp?ref=9780745646657) by Michael Bacon.

**Edit** (in response to comments): Consider Wittgenstein's famous dictum "meaning as use".  That's a slogan, but it is often offered as a kind of definition, "meaning is use".  The problem is it looks like a definition of meaning, which it is not, and the word "use" inevitably suggests instrumental use.  But the kind of practices involved are not necessarily instrumental, at least not for the individual.  E.g. "Ouch!" - there's no goal achieved by squeeling that, as far as I can see.  It's easy to imagine many less elementary cases.

Replace "meaning as use" with "practices explain signficance" and you get closer to contemporary pragmatism.  More technical:  normative practices institute conceptual content.  It's really the normativity that makes the difference.  Here the risk is infinite regress: to apply a first-level rule, you have to have a 2nd-level rule telling how to apply the first-level rule.  To apply the 2nd-level rule, you need a 3rd-level rule, and so on ad infinitum.  This is where practice comes it: it halts the regress.  At some point we say "that's just the way we do things around here."  So practice is the unexplained explainer.

The normativity of practice is instituted socially, by punishment of deviation from norms and reward of conformance.  If you use a word in a way that does not conform to community standards your interactions in the community are more likely to result in failure.  This is where Pragmatism is deeply related to evolutionary thinking.

As to circularity and the need for Pragmatism to explain its own terms I guess the question would be something like, if normative practices explain conceptual content, then what is it for normative practices to explain the conceptual content of "normative practices".  Point one: we've already rejected the idea that we need to explain some mysterious semantic relation between the term "normative practices" and something in the world that we describe using that term.  Second, it's not the *term* "normative practices" that does the explanatory work, its the practices themselves, which can be observed and studied scientifically, unlike whatever it is that "true" and "refers" are supposed to mean.  So in looking to our practices to explain our term "practices" there is no circularity.  Just think of it as "look at what we do when we employ the term 'practice' and that will tell you what the term 'means' (to us, at least)"; this does not require an antecedent definition of "practice" that needs explanation.  Or maybe think of "normative practices explain conceptual content" (or whatever your preferred pragmatism slogan is) as a *methodological* recipe rather than a definition.

Dunno how convincing that is but it's about the best this non-professional can do.  If you really want to dig into this I highly recommend Bacon's Intro or Robert Brandom's [Articulating Reasons](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674006928).  FWIW reading Brandom changed my life, no lie.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out response. I do still have a few questions. Firstly, you note that the terms of pragmatism are not 'philosophically mysterious', unlike 'truth'. This seems to be your reason why pragmatism needn't explain its own terms. But this doesn't really settle well with me. Just what qualifies something as 'useful'? If it is simply that something has the capacity to be used for a certain purpose, this leaves the door open for all kinds of statements as being 'useful', though obviously unacceptable (such as Russell's 'Santa Claus exists' statement).

Comment: And to be fair, you did note that the problem is more complex and subtle than your account of it indicates (I'm mostly asking out of interest than criticism). Secondly, I am also skeptical of how pragmatism can be only an 'attitude'. What sort of attitude would it be? Furthermore, why would it be so controversial if it were only an attitude? It just seems like a way to evade answering to the consequences and presuppositions inherent within it.

Comment: Excellent points - I realize I omitted two critical pragmatic notions, namely normativity and the social dimension of normative practices.  Alas I'm on the cellphone again, will edit my answer in a bit.  Re: attitude, I can't think of anything better.  Pragmatism is not a single doctrine or theory, nor a system, does not claim to be the One True Philosophy.  So I think of it as an attitude or orientation in the same way I think of science like that.  Compare Wittgenstein's "way of life".

Comment: P.S.  I think one reason Pragmatism is so controversial is because it is so revolutionary.   If you tell professional philosophers there are no important questions in their field, that philosophy is at best therapeutic, or just another literary genre (Rorty) you can expect a little pushback.  Most contemporary Pragmatists don't go that far but even then Pragmatism is opposed to ways of thinking (representationalism, etc.) that have dominated Western thought for centuries.  Price, for example, denies that science has any claim to special knowledge, says science is essentially pluralistic.

Comment: Cool beans. I have another question going along these same lines that I plan on mulling over. In the meanwhile I'll allow you to edit your answer before commenting further.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think your edits answer the question very well along with answering other comments I would have made. It seems to me to be the case that whereas realists halt their own explanatory regress in reality itself, pragmatists halt the explanatory regress in 'practice', as you say. The realist in me still can't help but balking at this though (admittedly for reasons I can't quite articulate). Something just seems off to me about holding that 'practice' can really end the regress (at least the regress realists are concerned about).

Comment: What seems to me to be the point where we diverge is what we allow in our range of possibilities from the get-go. For the pragmatist, the only regress to be accounted for is that which can be hashed out in terms of use. But for the realist, the regress to be accounted for is something altogether different. What leaves me still puzzled is this underlying reasoning about which school allows for the proper possibilities. It seems to me to be the case that the content of our conception of something comes before the description or account of our conception therein.

Comment: In other words, to say that we can account for conceptual content in certain terms seems to follow the fact of our conceptual content. The realist might say that meaning, truth and other such notions come as facts about our mental existence before our description of them, so that whatever we say about our conceptual content therein it is (seemingly) confused to try to replace these notions with something else (such as 'use'). One might therefore accept pragmatism insofar as it is a positive account of the origin of words or behavior, but not as a negative account of our concepts.

Comment: And, as another brief point, you mention that what is ending the regress is simply 'practical bearings' itself. But, under pragmatism, 'practical bearings' is a phrase we utter, a group of words. If this phrase bears no meaning and no reference to *practical bearings itself* then pragmatism seems to not really explain anything. At the same time, if the phrase 'practical bearings' *does* refer, or *signify* something outside of it (*practical bearings itself*) then pragmatism is being unfair to realists who hold (again seemingly) the exact same thing. But I might just be utterly confused.

Comment: "Practical bearings" is your term, not mine.  I don't think I can add anything useful to what I've already said, so my recommendation is that, if you really want to understand pragmatism you should go to the source.  "Articulating Reasons" by R. Brandom is brief and readable.  His "Making It Explicit" is big and dense but the first part offers a very detailed analysis of the sort of question you're asking.  Rorty, Hilary Putnam, Huw Price are some others.  Bacon's "Pragmatism: An Introduction" might be the best place to start.

Comment: @Esse "Practical bearings" is Peirce's term from his pragmatic maxim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_maxim, and there was indeed a problem with his attempted application of it to individual concepts. It was only later realized by Quine and others that expressions do not refer or signify individually, they play a role in a language which responds to "something outside of it" as a system. But just because "practical" does not refer or signify doesn't mean that it does not share in the meaningfulness of language as a "form of life", in Wittgenstein's word.

Answer (score 0):

Any system gets murky once it starts talking about its own truth values, not just pragmatism.

If the system is a sufficiently powerful formal language, declaring the Truth value of its statements within the system itself is impossible, as proven by [Tarksi's undefinnability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem).  "Sufficiently powerful" is defined as being able to prove all of the truths in arithmetic, such as 1+1=2, and 5*4 = 20.

We can consider weaker systems, but if we weaken them too much, pragmatism cannot be proven invalid.  The "circular reasoning" of pragmatism can easily be short circuited and turned into a recursive series of systems with a boundless number of iterations.  Without laws of arithmetic that handle boundless series, it can be markedly hard to disprove the value of pragmatism.

This leaves informal systems.  It is not clear whether it is possible to prove that two individuals have the same interpretation of an informal system or not.  Obviously if interpretations differ, truth values can differ.

All of this suggests that pragmatism can never claim to have the one and only answer for every question.  However, pragmatically speaking, there are many series of iterations on words which we are generally comfortable having a mathematical limit as to how much misinterpreration can be had. Pragmatically, a realizable system which has a limit pointing towards the behaviors you want to see is more useful than an unrealizable idealized system which has the behavior you want to see.

Comment: While it can be granted for the sake of argument that any formal language's truth-values cannot be represented by the said formal language itself, this seems to fly high of the point of the question, which is concerned not so much with truth-value, but rather with what is simply meant at all by a given formal language, in this case, what is meant by pragmatism. I'm not sure what you mean by stating that 'pragmatism can easily be short circuited... with a boundless number of iterations'. Would you mind clarifying a bit?

Comment: @Esse I was targeting, somewhat, the comments on the question.  As for short circuiting, take any string of text which is purported to define the nature of pragmatism.  Interpret it using whatever interpretation makes sense.  Use that interpretation to develop a more pragmatic interpretation.  Then do it again, interpreting the text even more pragmatically, to determine a better undersatnding of the nature of pragmatism.  And so forth.  It turns a circular argument into an infinite regress.  In the formal language world, tarski approached this with his (L,N) tuples, where L is the language

Comment: and N is the interpretation of the language.  He insisted the semantic meaning could only be acquired from (L, N), not just L itself.  He proved it for formal languages.  However, if we step away from formality, and go to informal languages, a more informal argument is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems that, while your suggestion is interesting, it still succumbs to circularity. The problem, as I see it, is when you say "Interpret it using whatever interpretation makes sense. Use that interpretation to develop a more pragmatic interpretation." All such suggestions assume an interpretation, and don't really provide us with an answer to the question of what pragmatism, or in this case 'pragmatic', is. What does it mean to 'develop a more pragmatic interpretation'? Isn't that the very question being asked? I might just be confused here though.

Comment: @Esse It's only circular if you come back to the interpretation you had before.  As long as the interpretations keep evolving, it's a redicution to infinity, not a circular argument.  It's basically what we have computers do when we have them run optimizers.  They take a guess, see what the state-space looks like around that guess, then make a better educated guess based on what they learned.  The goal is convergence.  If it converges on a definition, then that iterative process works.  A pragmatist would argue that definitions based on "practical bearings" will converge (because it is

Comment: practical for them to do so)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but isn't the point of contention not the iterations themselves but the persistent standard that endures throughout each iteration which allows for convergence to occur at all? The point that I'm making, insofar as I understand the problem, is that where it might be true that explanations of what pragmatism is can be hashed out in 'boundless iterations', it cannot be true that the rules by which such iterations converge can themselves be hashed in the same way under the same formal language. What allows for the standard of making something 'pragmatic'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39193/discussion-between-cort-ammon-and-esse).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inconsistent about intersubjectivity, but there is nothing definite about it either.

A clearer way of putting the philosophy of language you describe here is the Wittgenstein's formulation in terms of language-games.  He suggests the best way to look at language is as a set of overlapping games, each with a slightly different set of rules about how words combine and maintain their meaning.  To call them games is perhaps a bit too lighthearted, they are all deadly earnest, but they have the form of a game, with rules and moves and often, but not always, winners and losers.

We have a game of Government, in which we encode decisions about fairness through precedents and statutes.  It includes a game of finance, which controls how we decide prices, etc.  Each religion has its own game in which things mean slightly different things from what they mean in other religions, and we have a meta-game of God-talk that tries to coordinate the discussions of religions -- mostly so that religion as an institution gets respected by the Law.

The games then modify each other, and constitute larger games about the modifications.  We have a meta-game of English grammar that continually modifies all the games that are conducted in English, for instance, as our language evolves.  We have a meta-game of Science that modifies the way we talk about other things as we converge on a common network of explanatory concepts that predict the success of our technology.

One can object that this is all circular.  It is, but not in a way that degenerates.  It works like the organs of a human body.  The system of games maintains its own homeostasis through use, the same way your body maintains homeostasis via living.

Your circulatory system does its job, and it is constantly being modified by all the other systems of the body, which put things into it and taken them out.  Your liver controls the concentrations of various enzymes by modifying the blood.  Your digestion pushes around fats and sugars in ways that are modified by the liver...  There is nothing wrong with the circularity of the fact that the tissues of the Liver need the products of the digestive process that the liver regulates.  It means that neither the liver nor the digestion can have come first, and that is fine.  They came together.

The problem with this all is that it makes philosophy messy, more like biology and less like physics or math, and that makes issues of belief complex.  But you can't argue with reality on the basis that it offends your naivete.